# Backbone and TypeScript, an unhappy marriage: Building a type-safe "get"?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, typescript

I am trying to use TypeScript with Backbone.js.  It "works", but much of the type safety is lost by Backbone's get() and set().  I am trying to write a helper method that would restore type-safety.  Something like this:

I'd put this in my model:

```
object() : IMyModel  {
    return attributes; // except I should use get(), not attributes, per documentation
}
```

And this in the consumer:
    `var myVar = this.model.object().MyProperty;`

With this syntax, I get TypeScript's knowledge that MyProperty exists and is bool, which is awesome.  However, the [backbone.js docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes) tell me to use get and set rather than the attributes hash directly.  So is there any magic Javascript way to pipe usage of that object through get and set properly?

Comment: Not an answer but I found the same problem and went with a different set of tools to manage data and binding (plain but strongly typed TS objects + Linq.js + jsrender/jsviews (with its observable class - http://bit.ly/WyNbhn)) for this very reason. Refs: http://linqjs.codeplex.com/ https://github.com/BorisMoore

Comment: I think you might need to wait for TypeScript to support generics to do this in a sane way (v0.9)

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Being that current answer is unaccepted, falls apart with more complex objects like arrays, and TypeScript having support for generics now, perhaps you can provide an updated answer?

Comment: @parliament I've added a new answer that is way less verbose and uses generics. Hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 17):

We are using backbone with TypeScript heavily, and have come up with a novel solution.
Consider the following code:

```
interface IListItem {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    Description: string;
}

class ListItem extends Backbone.Model implements IListItem {
    get Id(): number {
        return this.get('Id');
    }
    set Id(value: number) {
        this.set('Id', value);
    }
    set Name(value: string) {
        this.set('Name', value);
    }
    get Name(): string {
        return this.get('Name');
    }
    set Description(value: string) {
        this.set('Description', value);
    }
    get Description(): string {
        return this.get('Description');
    }

    constructor(input: IListItem) {
        super();
        for (var key in input) {
            if (key) {
                //this.set(key, input[key]);
                this[key] = input[key];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the interface defines the properties of the model, and the constructor ensures that any object passed will have the Id, Name and Description properties.  The for statement simply calls backbone set on each property.  Such that the following test will pass:

```
describe("SampleApp : tests : models : ListItem_tests.ts ", () => {
    it("can construct a ListItem model", () => {
        var listItem = new ListItem(
            {
                Id: 1,
                Name: "TestName",
                Description: "TestDescription"
            });
        expect(listItem.get("Id")).toEqual(1);
        expect(listItem.get("Name")).toEqual("TestName");
        expect(listItem.get("Description")).toEqual("TestDescription");

        expect(listItem.Id).toEqual(1);

        listItem.Id = 5;
        expect(listItem.get("Id")).toEqual(5);

        listItem.set("Id", 20);
        expect(listItem.Id).toEqual(20);
    });
});
```

**Update:**
I have updated the code base to use ES5 get and set syntax, as well as the constructor.  Basically, you can use the Backbone .get and .set as internal variables.

Comment: Is listItem.Name == 'TestName' too?  If not, why are those props defined?  What if I use listItem.set("Name", "NewName"), I'd need that to reflect in both places...

Comment: ok, so I've tweaked the code to use ES6 getter and setter syntax.  Let me know if this works for you.  Have fun

Comment: This topic has inspired me to post a quick blog on strongly typed backbone models : http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2013/03/20/typescript-strongly-typed-backbone-models/

Comment: Like the way you model the variable with Typescript. I'll definetly play around with it. It's not but almost like you modeling the vos in oop language : )

Comment: One gotcha here is if you want to reset the whole model (not just one of it's properties) you should do `this.model.set(new BackBoneModel())` not `this.model = new BackBoneModel()` otherwise it'll complain when you try to bind an event like so `this.model.on(...)`  ... "on" will be undefined

Comment: @parliament We usually do model.set(model.defaults()) to 'reset' a model.

Answer (score 10):

I've come up with the following using generics and ES5 getters/setters, building off of the [/u/blorkfish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/391150/blorkfish) answer.

```
class TypedModel<t> extends Backbone.Model {
    constructor(attributes?: t, options?: any) {
        super(attributes, options);

        var defaults = this.defaults();
        for (var key in defaults) {
            var value = defaults[key];

            ((k: any) => {
                Object.defineProperty(this, k, {
                    get: (): typeof value => {
                        return this.get(k);
                    },
                    set: (value: any) => {
                        this.set(k, value);
                    },
                    enumerable: true,
                    configurable: true
                });
            })(key);
        }
    }

    public defaults(): t {
        throw new Error('You must implement this');
        return <t>{};
    }
}
```

Note: Backbone.Model defaults is optional, but since we use it to build the getters and setters, it is now mandatory. The error that is thrown forces you to do this. Perhaps we can think of a better way?

And to use it:

```
interface IFoo {
    name: string;
    bar?: number;
}

class FooModel extends TypedModel<IFoo> implements IFoo {
    public name: string;
    public bar: number;

    public defaults(): IFoo {
        return {
            name: null,
            bar: null
        };
    }
}

var m = new FooModel();
m.name = 'Chris';
m.get('name'); // Chris
m.set({name: 'Ben', bar: 12});
m.bar; // 12
m.name; // Ben

var m2 = new FooModel({name: 'Calvin'});
m2.name; // Calvin
```

It's slightly more verbose than ideal, and it requires you to use the defaults, but it works well.

Comment: +1 I like it I haven't tried this but it looks like it will work. However, how would it deal with arrays? For example is `m.SomeArray.push(item)`, will this trigger Backbone events? The native backbone way it pretty ugly you have to get the model, push the item, set the model. (`var array = m.get("SomeArray"); array.push(item); m.set("SomeArray", array);`) . Can your implementation make this more natural?

Comment: Your example method won't work since your set is basically not doing anything. array === m.get('SomeArray') since they object reference is the same. You would have to do a silent unset and then a set, clone the array and set the value to the new array, or perhaps manually trigger a change event?

Comment: Either way, my implementation just calls the Backbone get and set calls so any workarounds you would have to do are the same.

Comment: This errors on: 
`var value = defaults[key];` 
in TypedModel:
`error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.`

for me in TypeScript 1.5. Anyone found a reasonable workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using decorators, create a base class like this:

```
export class Model<TProps extends {}> extends Backbone.Model {

    static Property(fieldName: string) {
        return (target, member, descriptor) => {
            descriptor.get = function() {
                return this.get(fieldName);
            };
            descriptor.set = function(value) {
                this.set(fieldName, value);
            };
        };
    }

    attributes: TProps;
}
```

Then create your own classes like this:

```
class User extends Model<{id: string, email: string}> {
    @Model.Property('id')        set Id(): string { return null; }
    @Model.Property('email')     set Email(): string { return null; }
}
```

And use it:

```
var user = new User;
user.Email = 'email@me.ok';
console.log(user.Email);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with the same issue but I guess I found and interesting solution with the from TypeScript chatgroup. The solution seems pretty promising and I would like to share it here. 
So my code now looks like this

```
//Define model structure
interface IMarkerStyle{
    Shape:string;
    Fill:string;
    Icon:string;
    Stroke:string;
};

export class MarkerStyle extends StrongModel<IMarkerStyle>{
```

```
//Usage
let style=new MarkerStyle();

//Most interesting part. Oddly enough thease lines check for type
style.s("Fill","#F00"); //setter OK:  Fill is defined as string
style.s("Fill",12.3);   //setter ERROR: because of type mismatch
```

Another benefit I got is it checks defaults and constructor parameters for complience with the interface. So static type checking will not allow you to specify a default value for a property that does not exist

```
let style=new MarkerStyle(
  {
    Shape:"circle", //OK 
    Phill:"#F00",   //ERROR typo in field name
    Icon:"car"      //OK
                    //ERROR Stroke is not optional in interface and not specified here
  }
);
```

Comment: Here is the secret sauce
`class StrongModel<T> extends Backbone.Model{
    constructor(attr?:T,opt?:any ){
        super(attr,opt);
    }
    g<K extends keyof T>(prop:K ):T[K]{
        return super.get(<string>prop);
    }
    s<K extends keyof T>(prop:K , val:T[K]){
         super.set(<string>prop,val);
    }
    defaults(){
        return this.def();
    }
    def():T{
        return null;
    }
    json():T{
        return this.toJSON();
    }    
}`