# Getting nested backbone model attributes using some expression

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using Backbone model shown below

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
      name: 'user',
      address: {
        city: '',
        state: '',
        area: {
         code: '',
         street: ''
         //More properties
        }
      }
  });
```

So I can able to access nested **street** property using

```
 model.get('address').area.street
```

Now I have a string like

```
 properties = 'area.street'
```

How do I use it to access the nested street property?

Is there any way from where we can directly access nested properties ?

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially flatten the nesting with Underscore's `flatten` method, which will put the object in a one-item array and put `street` at the top level of that object:

```
var flatAddress = _.flatten(model.get('address'))
```

That doesn't quite help if you're working off `'area.street'`. Given a string representing layers of dot notation, the string likely needs to be broken up in a way that JS objects can digest. Consider something like

```
var array = properties.split('.');
var fromAddress = model.get('address');
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
  fromAddress = fromAddress[array[i]];
}
```

or if `Array.reduce` is available/preferable:

```
var property = properties.split('.').reduce(function(prev,curr) {
  return prev[curr];
}, model.get('address'));
```

Either would be worth putting as a property on the model to facilitate reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298215/backbone-and-typescript-an-unhappy-marriage-building-a-type-safe-get) - the answers show how to use a constructor on your backbone.model and then do this:

```
constructor(input: IListItem) {
    super();
    for (var key in input) {
        if (key) {
            //this.set(key, input[key]);
            this[key] = input[key];
        }
    }
}
```

using the this[key] = input[key] method of creating Backbone Models will allow you to write code like this:

```
model.get('address').get('area').get('street')
```

if you use ES5 syntax ( as described in the answer ) - you can even write code like this:

```
model.Address.Area.Street
```

Also, you may find [this blog](http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2013/03/20/typescript-strongly-typed-backbone-models/) post helpful.